# Random Numbers in Android

Tags: java, android, random

I know there are a lot of topics about random number generation in Android and Java in general. I am currently programming an app that rolls 5 dices. I currently use `Random()` to generate these numbers. This is my code:

```
Random r = new Random();

a[0] = r.nextInt(6)+1;
a[1] = r.nextInt(6)+1;
a[2] = r.nextInt(6)+1;

d[0] = r.nextInt(6)+1;
d[1] = r.nextInt(6)+1;
```

Documentation says that `Random()` without custom seed is sufficient for most tasks. Is it still random enough when I generate 5 random numbers in such short time? Is there any difference if I generate a new `Random()` object after each random number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a new seed each time you generate a random number. The same seed will generate the same random sequence of numbers so you have to worry about generating an unpredictable seed. The default constructor `Random()` will generate a seed *partially* based on current time which should be sufficient for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use a custom seed (e.g. based on time or some such non-easily-repeatable itme), then your results will repeat each time you execute (i.e. you will get the same sequence of pseudo random numbers).

You want to add a custom seed so that successive executions of your program do not always have the same result.

While it is not necessary for a simple homework question to use a custom seed, it would be a good idea to add use of a custom seed (so you learn about how to do that and why it may be needed for more complex problem solving).

Comment: `Random()` empty constructor used seed based on the time, therefore leading to a different sequences in each run. If you use the same custom seed then you'll get same results.